# Call Postgres procedure / function with refcursor input

Tags: postgresql

I'm porting an Oracle function to Postgres which has one of the input parameters as refcursor type. The ported Postgres function looks as below.

```
create or replace function gt_mlt_dtls(dtl_cur IN REFCURSOR, flag TEXT, dt DATE)
returns........
```

How do I pass the value for `dtl_cur` parameter as `REFCURSOR`? In Oracle, `CURSOR(some select query)` works for inputting a refcursor. Is it possible in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `DECLARE` the cursor in SQL and pass its name to the procedure:

```
BEGIN;

DECLARE c CURSOR FOR SELECT ...;

CALL gt_mlt_dtls('c', 'text', current_date);

COMMIT;
```

To call it from another procedure, call

```
DECLARE
   c refcursor;
BEGIN
   OPEN c FOR SELECT ...;
   CALL gt_mlt_dtls(c, ...);
```

Comment: Thanks, how can I call this function(with refcursor input parameter) inside another procedure ?